# How to edit web.xml using Jenkins Build Paremeter

Tags: xml, maven, jenkins

I want to edit some configuration in my web.xml file based on Jenkins Build Paraemter.

Here's my build goal in Jenkins:

```
clean compile war:war -Dparameter=$PARAMETER
```

And here's my web.xml file:

```
...
<env-entry> 
    <env-entry-name>parameter</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>${parameter}</env-entry-value> 
</env-entry>
...
```

Is this possible? Or should I use another way?

I'm new to Maven project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to activate [*filtering* (which is in fact string/variable interpolation) on the Maven Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) for every resources folder which contains resources to be filtered:

```
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>  <!-- re-define the default since an explicit
                                                        <resources> declaration overwrites it -->
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>  <!-- contains web.xml, for example -->
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
```

And, BTW, you don't have to and should not invoke the `war` goal of the [Maven WAR Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) on the command line explicitely, since:

> `war:war` is the default goal invoked during the `package` phase for projects with a packaging type of `war`. It builds a WAR file.

I.e. `mvn clean package ...` achieves the same (and is the intended usage of the [Maven Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. So, if my web.xml file is in WebContent/WEB-INF, then I should change the <directory> value to WebContent/WEB-INF right? And about the goal, shouldn't I compile it first before packaging?

Comment: @skltrbk 1) Basically, yes (if you need `/WEB-INF` in the resulting WAR it's just `WebContent`). 2) During a Maven build all phases up to and including the given phase are passed. So, `compile` (among others) is passed prior to `package` implicitely.

Comment: 1) I've tried your solution but it doesn't work. My solution is adding <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors> in maven-war-plugin and then add <parameter> tag inside <properties> in pom.xml. 2) I see, thank you for the explanation